# Show that $\frac{(n-a)^2}{n}$ can be written as $1-\left(\frac{n}{a}\right)^2\cdot\frac{n}{(n/a)^2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

\left(\frac{n}{a}\right)^2\cdot\frac{n}{(n/a)^2}$.

I have got so far to $(a^2/n)-2a+n$

But I can not see how to proceed. Can anyone help please?

Comment: Are you asking to show that $$\frac{(n-a)^2}{n}=1-\left(\frac{n}{a}\right)^2\cdot\frac{n}{(n/a)^2}$$ since it is very hard to read your expressions when they are not TeX-formatted and have syntax errors regarding brackets ...

Comment: Yes I have edited to try to make it clearer

Comment: I think you want $(1-n/a)^2*n/(n/a)^2 $

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\frac{(n-a)^2}{n} =(n-a)^2\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) =(n-a)^2\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\frac{a^2}{a^2} =\left(\frac{n-a}{a}\right)^2 \frac{a^2}{n}= \left(\frac{n}{a}-1\right)^2 \frac{a^2}{n} = \left(\frac{n}{a}-1\right)^2 \frac{n^2}{n^2} \frac{a^2}{n}  = (-1)^2\left(1-\frac{n}{a}\right)^2 \frac{n}{(\frac{n}{a})^2}=\left(1-\frac{n}{a}\right)^2 \frac{n}{(\frac{n}{a})^2}$$

The real trick here is multiplying by $1=\frac{a^2}{a^2}=\frac{n^2}{n^2}$.

Comment: Thank you I can follow most of it but not the first step to \left(\frac{n-a}{a}\right)^2 \frac{a^2}{n} could you explain how we end up with this especially the first term with a on the bottom and how you knew to do this please.

Comment: @Duvessa Multiplying by some form of one is common trick you just have to learn. Apologies there was a mistake in the first step. Have added to another to help explain it.

Comment: Thank you that is a lot clearer I will work through and try to figure where (n-a)/a comes from

Answer (score 0):

**Hint :** $(n-a)=a(\frac{n}{a}-1)$